# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10 error

Tags: android

i have four activities using a single adapter to display a spinner. 2 of the activities working fine while calling the adapter but 2 of them crashes . Giving **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10 error** .

Here's the code

This activity doesnt crash and shows the spinners and its items perfectly

```
public class ArcherTowerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Spinner sp1;
    Spinner sp2;
    Spinner sp3;
    Spinner sp4;
    Spinner sp5;
    Spinner sp6;
    Spinner sp7;
    Spinner sp8;
    TextView tx;
    Button sbmt;
    String levels[]={"Level 1",
            "Level 2",
            "Level 3",
            "Level 4",
            "Level 5",
            "Level 6",
            "Level 7",
            "Level 8",
            "Level 9",
            "Level 10",
            "Level 11",
            "Level 12",
            "Level 13",
            "Level 14",};
    int[] images={
            R.drawable.archer_tower1,
            R.drawable.archer_tower2,
            R.drawable.archer_tower3,
            R.drawable.archer_tower4,
            R.drawable.archer_tower5,
            R.drawable.archer_tower6,
            R.drawable.archer_tower7,
            R.drawable.archer_tower8,
            R.drawable.archer_tower9,
            R.drawable.archer_tower10,
            R.drawable.archer_tower11,
            R.drawable.archer_tower12,
            R.drawable.archer_tower13,
            R.drawable.archer_tower14,
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_archer_tower);

        sbmt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.upgradeResult);
        sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        sp5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        sp6=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        sp7=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
        sp8=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        SpinnerAdapter adapter=new SpinnerAdapter(this,levels,images);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp4.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp5.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp6.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp7.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp8.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This activity fails to do so

```
public class MortarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner sp1;
    Spinner sp2;
    Spinner sp3;
    Spinner sp4;

    TextView tx;
    Button sbmt;
    String levels[]={"Level 1",
            "Level 2",
            "Level 3",
            "Level 4",
            "Level 5",
            "Level 6",
            "Level 7",
            "Level 8",
            "Level 9",
            "Level 10",
           };
    int[] images={
            R.drawable.mortar1,
            R.drawable.mortar2,
            R.drawable.mortar3,
            R.drawable.mortar4,
            R.drawable.mortar5,
            R.drawable.mortar6,
            R.drawable.mortar7,
            R.drawable.mortar8,
            R.drawable.mortar9,
            R.drawable.mortar10,

    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mortar);

        sbmt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.upgradeResult); 
        sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        SpinnerAdapter adapter=new SpinnerAdapter(this,levels,images);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp4.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the Adapter code

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String>{


Context c;

    String[] levels;
    int[] images;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context ctx,String[] levels, int[] images){

        super(ctx,R.layout.spinner_building_to_upgrade,levels);
        this.c=ctx;
        this.images=images;
        this.levels=levels;


    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_building_to_upgrade,null);
        }

        TextView tx=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.levelNumber);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageid);

        //SET DATA
        tx.setText(levels[position]);
        image.setImageResource(images[position]);




        return convertView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_building_to_upgrade,null);
        }

        TextView tx=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.levelNumber);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageid);

        //SET DATA
        tx.setText(levels[position]);
        image.setImageResource(images[position]);



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

First Activity has 14 items and Second Activity has 10 items in it.And Second one crashes giving  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10 error .

EDIT :

I have figured out the problem that if i enter Items less than 10 in the array Adapter it crashes and give error. Why is it so? As i have not set any maximum minimum lenght.I want to send 8 items in the spinner Adapter. Please Help

Error Log

```
01-11 17:44:51.066 19769-19769/com.curtztech.android.clashmate E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
01-11 17:44:51.206 19769-19769/com.curtztech.android.clashmate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.curtztech.android.clashmate, PID: 19769
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
at com.curtztech.android.clashmate.SpinnerAdapter.getView(SpinnerAdapter.java:74)
at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:592)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:540)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:502)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java:1183)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 17:45:00.036 20127-20127/? E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:198)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 17:45:01.006 1230-2336/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.settings.applications.SpProvider
01-11 17:45:01.006 20160-20160/? E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:198)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 17:45:57.236 1230-2340/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.settings.applications.SpProvider
01-11 17:45:57.286 1230-1240/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.settings.applications.SpProvider
01-11 17:46:37.266 1230-1742/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02: E/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::setXtraData(char*, int):1117]: failed status = eLOC_CLIENT_SUCCESS, inject_pos_ind.status = eQMI_LOC_GENERAL_FAILURE_V02, part num = 25, ind.partNum = 0
```

Comment: on which line is the error?

Comment: override `count()` method to return total records

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, he passes `levels` in `super` constructor, which should not require overriding of `getCount()`

Comment: he should have to override count method to let the adapter know of the changes occurring in the data because he using the same adapter for multiple spinners, on which some have 14 elements and some have 10

Comment: Check out my Edit to the question @VladMatvienko

Comment: then pass array of 8 items instead of what you do now. It's really simple - if you want to show 8 - pass 8. Why you pass more?

Comment: Yes when i pass array of items less than 10, it gives that error i asked above, But when i passed array of 14 or 12 items , it works fine , screen doesnt crash.  @VladMatvienko

Comment: Clash of clans?

Comment: yes @KNeerajLal

Answer (score 1):

Implement this method;

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return levels.length;
}
```

Comment: Check out the Edit to my question